# What type of encoding used in example and how to do it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, encode

I have an url with json file and parameters. They coded:

?.lk.:1x:3c:34:2t:32:37:2x:3a:2t:2q:39:3d:2t:36

I tried to google, but have not success. ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the values by colon `':'`, get the numerical values of hex values and  build a string from this char codes.

Voilà!

```
Expensivebuyer
```

```js
var string = '.lk.:1x:3c:34:2t:32:37:2x:3a:2t:2q:39:3d:2t:36';
    values = string.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v, 36) || v);

console.log(String.fromCharCode(...values));
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanx a lot!